# Does makeEwsRequestAsync work in Hybrid mode?

Tags: exchangewebservices, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

An Outlook Office JavaScript add-in makes EWS requests to handle forwarding emails for the user. The code gets some details from the local context but then makes SOAP calls via makeEwsRequestAsync to have the server do the actual work. We are moving to Hybrid Exchange mode, and I was uncertain as to whether the code would continue working. I was not involved with the testing, and it is likely the testers did not test the add-in with newly created Exchange Online accounts, but I can't be certain. I do remember it working with on-premise accounts.

The current Office JavaScript add-in does not use AutoDiscover, but does make EWS calls, as so:

```
        _mailbox = Office.context.mailbox;
```

[snip]

```
        _mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(soapToGetItemData, soapToGetItemDataCallback);
```

Will this break oi Hybrid mode? Will it only work for on-premise accounts, but accounts created in Exchange Online break?

FYI, I do plan on writing new code using OAuth 2.0, likely using the REST API, but that is not the immediate concern unless that is what is required to have the add-in continue working.

Comment: Do you mean Hybrid (Cloud) Deployment by Hybrid mode ? Have you tried the same for an Online account, and does it work consistently for On-premise accounts ?

Comment: I mean Exchange Server Hybrid deployment, combining on-Premises and Exchange Online. It works fine for On-Prem accounts, but we are testing hybrid, and was trying to get in front of this issue by asking if exchange online accounts would work seamlessly.

Comment: Yes, it works fine for exchange online accounts. For further reference, you can go through this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services

Answer (score 0):

Marking this as answered, by Outlook Add-ins Team:

> Yes, it works fine for exchange online accounts. For further reference, you can go through this
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services
>
> Outlook Add-ins Team